# drupal_get_form won't print the add node form

Tags: forms, drupal

Im trying to get drupal_get_form('ccknode_node_form') to work, but nothing prints.
I've tried for example drupal_get_form('user_register'), and that works.

Im sure its very simple problem, but i really need som help with this.
Thanks
/Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node_form` is located in `node.pages.inc` which is what you are missing. If you add

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

that should fix it.

Comment: That sort of worked, but i get an empty form array. It wont print fields or anything. Just the "bottom"-options of node_form (revision, authouring and publishing options). What i want is to print a cck_node_form in a custom block, but i cant get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

I am also having problems with drupal_get_form but the code below will return the form html.  Problem areas can be not calling the correct node_form.

```
function get_author_form() {
  //return node_form(NULL,NULL);
  //return drupal_get_form('author_form');
  return author_ajax_form('author');
}

 function author_ajax_form($type) {
  global $user;
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

  $types = node_get_types();
  $type = isset($type) ? str_replace('-', '_', $type) : NULL;
  // If a node type has been specified, validate its existence.
  if (isset($types[$type]) && node_access('create', $type)) {
    // Initialize settings:
    $node = array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => $type, 'language' => 'bbb','bbb' => 'TRUE');
    $output = drupal_get_form($type .'_node_form', $node);
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @andersandersson666,

As @googletorp said, you need to include the node.pages from node module as they said:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

Then, you need to use a new function in Drupal 7 to get the form:

```
$theFormHTMLified = drupal_render(node_add("ccknode"));
```

Now you can print or return the `$theFormHTMLified`.

Hope it helps